# How to edit a background of a list using EditorStyles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I must change the list background texture, that list are located in a node I use the asset xNode to do that.
[image]
That is the code of NodeEditor, is the class I use to edit the node layout.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using XNodeEditor;

[CustomNodeEditor(typeof(BaseNode))]
public class BaseNodeEditor : NodeEditor
{
    private static GUIStyle gl_label_normal;
    private static GUIStyle gl_label_bold;
    private static GUIStyle gl_header;

    private static GUIStyle gl_numberField;

    private static GUIStyle gl_objectField;

    public override void OnBodyGUI()
    {
        if (gl_label_normal == null) gl_label_normal = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.label);
        if (gl_label_bold == null) gl_label_bold = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        if (gl_numberField == null) gl_numberField = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.numberField);
        if (gl_objectField == null) gl_objectField = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.objectField);


        EditorStyles.objectField.normal.background = GetBackgroundTexture("#00000080");

        EditorStyles.numberField.normal.background = GetBackgroundTexture("#00000080");
        EditorStyles.numberField.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        EditorStyles.label.focused.textColor = Color.blue;
        EditorStyles.label.hover.textColor = Color.black;
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.black;
        EditorStyles.boldLabel.normal.textColor = Color.black;
        EditorStyles.boldLabel.hover.textColor = Color.black;

        base.OnBodyGUI();

        EditorStyles.label.normal = gl_label_normal.normal;
        EditorStyles.boldLabel.normal = gl_label_bold.normal;
        EditorStyles.numberField.normal = gl_numberField.normal;
        EditorStyles.objectField.normal = gl_objectField.normal;
    }
    
    public override void OnHeaderGUI()
    {
        if (gl_header == null) gl_header = new GUIStyle(NodeEditorResources.styles.nodeHeader);
        NodeEditorResources.styles.nodeHeader.normal.textColor = Color.black;
        base.OnHeaderGUI();
        NodeEditorResources.styles.nodeHeader.normal = gl_header.normal;
    }
    
    private Texture2D GetBackgroundTexture(string hexColor) {
        Color color = Color.white;
        ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(hexColor, out color);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do that, if some one knows please can help me?

I tryed to find in EditorStyles the element responsible to manage the background in list.

What I want is find the element responsible to change the list background texture.

Comment: Have you tried to simply overwrite he entire `GUI.color`? .. like `var color = GUI.color; GUI.color = Color.yellow; /*your list drawer here*/ GUI.color = color;`

Comment: @derHugo I hadn't used "GUI.color". I tested following your recommendation and it worked, thanks. But now I'm seeing that I'll have to edit the background color when the mouse is over the element, the title of the list is transparent, it's getting weird.